# pymysql - Get value from a query

Tags: python, pymysql

I am executing the query using pymysql in python.

> select (sum(acc_Value)) from accInfo where acc_Name = 'ABC'

The purpose of the query is to get the sum of all the values in acc_Value column for all the rows matchin acc_Name = 'ABC'.

The output i am getting when using cur.fetchone() is

> (Decimal('256830696'),)

Now how to get that value "256830696" alone in python. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a tuple, just take the 0th index

Comment: I am new to python. Suppose the output (Decimal('256830696'),) is getting stored in an output variable - sql_out. How to take the 0th index of sql_out. Thank you.

Comment: Is it in the form of dictionary (key,value) pair inside the tuple? and how to access the value alone from that?

Comment: No, it's not the form of a dictionary. It is literally just a tuple that contains only one value. All SQL works like this because it stops SQL Injection. `data = cur.fetchone(); data = data[0]`

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

It's a tuple, just take the 0th index

Comment: Thank you. I am new to python. Suppose the output (Decimal('256830696'),) is getting stored in an output variable - sql_out. How to take the 0th index of sql_out. Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to copy/paste my comment then you should at least convert it into a full answer by demonstrating how to do this